# Is there a word for when you don't understand something?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

Is there a word or idiom for when you don't understand something but you cannot exactly pinpoint or explain precisely what you don't understand? Not to understand a word just for usage but to understand an idea at all, for basic description. Here we are missing the tools to describe and as such the means to understand. What term describes this empty nearness to a concept.

Comment: The word is: ***“Huh??”***

Comment: A bit of context would greatly help here @Reid, because as you put it, I think there might be lots of answers that fit your description but don't exactly conform with the connotation you want to reach.

Comment: I mean, a bit of context or maybe and example, that should also help.

Comment: Like [unknown unknowns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_are_known_knowns)?

Comment: You mean confused?

Comment: There be a lot of words for that.

Answer (score 1):

A word for the state of not understanding something is "[incomprehension](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/incomprehension)". This is neutral on whether or not you can pinpoint what it is that you don't understand.

If you don't understand something and moreover don't know why, you might be described as "[bewildered](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/bewildered)" (the corresponding state is "[bewilderment](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/bewilderment)"). This suggests near total incomprehension.

If you understand something *wrong* you are guilty of "[misunderstanding](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/misunderstanding)". But this requires not just that you don't understand, but that further you do not realize that you have not understood.

If there is a (single) word which indicates that you don't understand something, don't exactly know why, but that your uncertainty is only slight, then it is unknown to me.

Answer (score 0):

Not to detract from the completeness of Marmitrob or the exquisite brevity of Jim above (Go Jim!) but it looks like the point of your question is the deliciously unclear nature of what exactly you are missing. You may not understand it if you knew but you would certainly know enough to form the polite question on the subject. But here it is just out of reach.

The idiom "On the tip of my tongue" describes a word or name that is present in the mind but somehow not quite available to practical use. There is not yet an idiom to describe such ideas whose basic structure eludes our understanding enough for description and clarification.

Searching for such a word is almost a description of itself.

Answer (score 0):

Befuddled

In a confused state of mind, unable to express oneself clearly.

Definition:
Confused and unable to think clearly.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/befuddled

Answer (score -1):

How about "don't fully grok"? Grok (from Robert Heinlein's *Stranger In A Strange Land*, 1961) means:

Definition of grok, transitive verb (from m-w.com)

> to understand profoundly and intuitively

"Don't fully grok" would mean that while the concept is understood, there is something important missing from that understanding.

Comment: Not sure about the downvotes, this expression is incredibly common in engineering circles. I think they expel you from MIT if you don't use it at least once per year.

Answer (score -2):

I didn't quite get that.

I'm afraid, I don't follow you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).